# Positioning externally loaded svg in D3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I've loaded an external svg image into my visualization using d3:

```
var foo = d3.xml("foo.svg", "image/svg+xml", function(xml) {
  document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
})
```

One thing I can't seem to figure out is how I can position this SVG. For example, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
foo.attr("x", 10)
   .attr("y", 10)
```

This doesn't work. How can I manipulate the position of an externally loaded SVG file with D3?

Comment: Just an initial thought, are you setting the attributes inside the callback? Otherwise, foo might not have been loaded yet...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm setting the attribute outside the callback. I just can't figure out how to manipulate the external svg once it is loaded?

Comment: My point is that if you are calling it outside the callback and the image has not yet been loaded, then setting the attributes won't work. What errors are you getting? Undefined?

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well. Placing the attributes inside the callback does seem to have an effect.

Comment: The error I get is: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<SVGSVGElement> has no method 'attr'`

Comment: Make sure foo is a d3 selection since attr is a method of a d3 selection, not of an SVG DOM element.

Comment: Cool, i can put that as an answer that you can accept then. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure foo is a d3 selection since attr is a method of a d3 selection, not of an SVG DOM element.